# is there a way to get ubuntu 20.04 to switch between a amd gpu to a nvidia gpu

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, radeon

Is there a way to get Ubuntu to switch from an AMD Radeon HD twin froze ii to an EVGA NVIDIA gtx 1070 without removing the AMD one.

Also, Ubuntu is currently using the AMD one for its main GPU, the reason why is so I could use the AMD one in a VM that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about switching between the GPU's in realtime to use for the host  machine on the same X server instance no, you can do very super specific tasks like hash computations and mining on a different GPU that is plugged in but generally for things like games or display it is not possible to do without SLI.

If you're talking about KVM GPU passthrough, absolutely, as long as you isolate it to the KVM instance the host won't do anything with the other card.